# Equivelant of blur for non-form elelments

Tags: jquery, events, blur

Here's my non-working example to demonstrate the kind of thing i'm looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/h2cQ6/2/

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the exact behavior you want to gain here? You can't have "blur" on an element that can't gain focus...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a tabindex to the div.

```
<div style="height: 100px; width: 100px; background: red;" tabindex=0></div>
```

Then it should work

http://jsfiddle.net/h2cQ6/5/

Click in the box and hit tab tab

Comment: Doesn't do anything in my browser.

Comment: That's the exact same link provided in the question. Copy-paste gone wrong I presume?

Answer (score 0):

I'm on a phone so can't see your example, but what's stopping you from using click, mouseover, etc.? Those events work on any element.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want mouseout.

```
$(function(){
   $('div').mouseout(function(){
       alert('Foo!')
   })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h2cQ6/3/